# How to get index of rows in AgGrid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I want to get row's index in [AgGrid](https://www.ag-grid.com/). How can I do it?

```
{
  headerName: 'row',
  align: 'center' as const,
  dataIndex: 'id',
  key: 'id',
  width: 20,
  valueGetter: column => column.rowIndex + 1,
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-formatters/) documentaion:

you can try this:

```
{
      headerName: 'row',
      align: 'center' as const,
      dataIndex: 'id',
      key: 'id',
      width: 20,
      valueGetter: params => params.node.rowIndex + 1,
},
```